# How to select column name and values both to display on a page?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a value from a row and want to display only such values where there is a value with column name

```
----------------
id name  gender
---------------
1  Bob   M
2  Anny  
3  Harry M
```

so I want to display 2 Anny with Id and gender only, that means if I select 1 there should be id, name, gender.

I am unable to figure out how to write code statement

Comment: Please share expected result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF my understanding is correct, You wanted to Select the name and Gender only when you search the id? is that right?

If that so:

Please try this

`SELECT id, gender FROM [your_table] WHERE id = 2`

**EDIT**

As I have said on the comment section, Please see this as reference.

```
SELECT IIF(gender IS NULL , name ,  name & ' ' &  gender) AS Info FROM [your_table]
```

Comment: this is just an example for a large table. i want to display the rows with column name where there is value. i mean only name as column name and no gender for id 2 and both name and gender for id 1

Comment: @NewBee1 can you provide a sample of your expected result?

Comment: @NewBee1 Oh. so my understading is incorrect. As I observed on your example, If there is no value on Gender, Only the name will appear? and if not, Both Name and gender will appear? Is that Right?

Comment: @NewBee1 , Glad to help :) Hope you accept this as the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to display 2 Anny with Id and gender only. `concat()` function will help you for this
`select concat(id,' ',name) as name , gender from table_name where id=2`